# Laravel: how to pass a variable to my basic layout

Tags: laravel, layout, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass a variable to my basic layout. This is because I need it in all pages.
I thought that writing something like that on my BaseController

```
protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $footertext = MyText::where('status', 1);
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout, ['footertext' =>$footertext ]);
        }
    }
}
```

And on my  I thought that writing something like that on my main.blade.php could work.

```
 {{ $footertext }}.
```

Instead I having this error,

**Undefined variable: footertext**

and after two hours of looking around...I didn't find any solution.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: try `compact('footertext')` instead of `['footertext' =>$footertext ]`

Comment: I Tried...still not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not long ago I was trying to do the same.

If you are using Laravel 5 you can edit the AppServiceProvider.php inside `app/Providers` and register a provider for this layout like:

```
public function boot()
{
  view()->composer('my.layout', function($view) {
    $myvar = 'test';
    $view->with('data', array('myvar' => $myvar));
  });
}
```

Now if you are using Laravel 4 I think it's more simple. In the `app/filters.php`:

```
View::composer('my.layout', function ($view) {
  $view->with('variable', $variable);
});
```

In both ways any variable you pass will be available to all templates that are extending the master template.

References:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-pass-variables-to-master-template
https://coderwall.com/p/kqxdug/share-a-variable-across-views-in-laravel?p=1&q=author%3Aeuantor

Comment: Ok. I'm using Laravel 4.2 but I got an error:
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

I tried also to pass the var as share var...but no results
View::share('footertext', $footertext);

Comment: OK ! It works.... I read https://coderwall.com/p/kqxdug/share-a-variable-across-views-in-laravel?p=1&q=author%3Aeuantor and I applied. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh, maybe it's because I missed a $ before view @RedCube . Sorry! I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

For laravel 5.3 I am using in `AppServiceProvider.php` inside `app/Providers`

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('layouts.master', function($view)
    {
        $view->with('variable', 'myvariable');
    });
}
```

Reference:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-pass-variables-to-master-template

*Dedicated Class inlcuded

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.6 none of these methods work.
`AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::share('key', 'value');
}
```

Where `View` is the facade `Illuminate\Support\Facades\View`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need to pass data from controller to view in laravel like working with database query, select option and more. it’s simple and easy with built in function in laravel. We can send data from controller to view easily with with() in laravel. Also there are more way to send or pass data to view from controller. I am describing some easy way how to pass data form controller to view in laravel.

**1. Passing an array :**

```
$data = array(
    'name'  => 'Rakesh',
    'email' => 'sharmarakesh395@gmail.com'
);

return View::make('user')->with($data);

//Accesing $data on view :-

{{$data}}
{{$data['email']}}
```

**2. Working with query :**

```
function view() {
  $q = Model::where('name', '=', 'Foo')->first(); 
  $users = Model::order_by('list_order', 'ASC')->get();
  return $view->with('users', $users)->with('q', $q);
}
//Accesing on view :-
{{ $q->name }}
```

Hope that help you :)